# Use of unresolved identifier 'SDKApplicationDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

This is the code for both `Google-signin` and `Facebook-signin`. `Google-signin` works perfectly fine but Facebook "`SDKApplicationDelegate`" won't seem to work. I have imported all my pod (`import FacebookCore, Facebook Login, FacebookShare`).

Why is `SDKApplication` not working?

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn
import FacebookCore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "1043921468178-epj1ms4mnc4tbf2j3vb0kudggfmtnc8b.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?,
                                                                sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                                annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
        let facebookDidHandle = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

         return googleDidHandle || facebookDidHandle
    }
```

Comment: Please embed your code instead of an image of your code.

Comment: try this one works for me. in application open url method --> `let facebookDidHandle:Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url as URL, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: nil)`

Comment: is this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem, the solution I found was to `import FBSDKCoreKit` and rename it to `ApplicationDelegate`, but what I've done is to downgrade version of `FacebookCore` and `FacebookLogin` to the previous one (I was using `0.5.0`) Facebook SDK seems to have a lot of bugs on this new version, I advise you to do the same.

Comment: pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 4.38.1'
  pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 4.38.1' not works, can you share how you downgrade lib?

Comment: my podfile looks like:
`pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.5.0'`
`pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.5.0'`
because the lib of FacebookCore and FacebookLogin is different from FBSDKCoreKit, try this and it will probably go to version `4.44.1` (as mine are)